# Selecting Max with Lots of Other Items

Tags: sql-server, max

Sorry for the poor title.  I wasn't sure how to describe my problem.  I've written a query that returns about 23,000 records.  A lot of those records have similar information and I want to only select the records with the maximum of the field `dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldBuddyLinkSigStrength`.  I've tried grouping by all of the other columns being selected, but it doesn't appear to work correctly.  I don't fully understand SQL, especially the max and group functions.  I can do simple max functions when I only want or need to select one thing.  I don't understand how it works when I want to select a bunch of other data.  Below is the query.

```
SELECT
    dbo.tblmeterinfo.fldMeterSerialNumber AS "MOP_FNP_Meter",
    dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldRBuddyId AS "MOP_FNP_FNID",
    dbo.TBLMETERMAINT.fldmeterid AS "Meter_ID_Helped",
    dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldCBuddyId AS "FNID_Helped",
    dbo.fn_dt(dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldRBuddyToi) AS "TOI",
    dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldBuddyLinkSigStrength AS "Sig_Str",
    dbo.TBLSAWN_CIS_INFO.SML AS "Buddy_SML",
    dbo.TBLMETERLIST.fldaddress AS "Buddy_Address",
    dbo.TBLSAWNGISCOORD.X_COORD AS "X_Coord",
    dbo.TBLSAWNGISCOORD.Y_COORD AS "Y_Coord"
FROM dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TBLMETERLIST
    ON (dbo.TBLMETERLIST.FLDREPID = dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldCBuddyId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TBLMETERMAINT
    ON (dbo.TBLMETERMAINT.FLDREPID = dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldCBuddyID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TBLSAWN_CIS_INFO
    ON (dbo.TBLSAWN_CIS_INFO.FLDREPID = dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldCBuddyId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TBLSAWNGISCOORD
    ON (dbo.TBLSAWNGISCOORD.SRV_MAP_LOC = dbo.TBLSAWN_CIS_INFO.SML)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblmeterinfo
    ON (dbo.tblmeterinfo.fldRepId = dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldRBuddyId)
WHERE dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldRBuddyId IN (SELECT
    dbo.tblSAWN_FNPmap.Repid
FROM dbo.tblSAWN_FNPmap)
AND dbo.TBLMETERMAINT.fldmeterid IS NOT NULL
```

The query below is simple and does what I want, but doesn't get all of the other field.  This query only returns 617 records.  I would like the above query to return 617 records, but include all of the other information I've selected.

```
SELECT
    dbo.TBLMETERMAINT.fldmeterid AS "Meter_ID_Helped",
    MAX(dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldBuddyLinkSigStrength) AS "Max_Sig"
FROM dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TBLMETERMAINT
    ON (dbo.TBLMETERMAINT.FLDREPID = dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldCBuddyID)
WHERE dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldRBuddyId IN (SELECT
    dbo.tblSAWN_FNPmap.Repid
FROM dbo.tblSAWN_FNPmap)
AND dbo.TBLMETERMAINT.fldmeterid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY dbo.TBLMETERMAINT.fldmeterid
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) to the rescue. You can use it to find the best records in a set, with a grouping by some subset or other. Something like

```
select * 
from ....
where row_number over (partition by id order by fldBuddyLinkSigStrength) = 1
```

So SQL Server assigns a row number within the groups. Each record will be sub-grouped by id, in this case, and given 1 if it's the best strength, 2 if it's next, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting duplicates have you tried using SELECT DISTINCT?

Basically how Max works is that it will select the highest value in the group.

So if you have a table:

```
ID     |   VALUE
1       |   10
1       |   7
1       |   9
2      |   6
2      |   8
```

And do

SELECT ID, MAX(VALUE)
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY ID

You'll get the max value per ID

```
ID    |  VALUE
1      |  10
2      | 8
```

If you want to get the Max while not grouping the result then you can do the group in a subselect

SELECT ID, VALUE, MAX_VALUE etc etc
FROM TABLE
JOIN ( SELECT ID, MAX(VALUE) AS MAX_VALUE FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID) as MAX ON MAX.ID = TABLE.ID

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try modifying the query Monday and report back. I think this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your table structures in more detail I can't be sure this is the best way, but here's something that should work.  Use the 2nd query as the left side of a left join, to pick up the extra columns:

```
select a.*
  from (<your 2nd query>) a
left join dbo.TBLMETERLIST 
    on (a.FLDREPID = dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8.fldCBuddyId)
left join <next table> ...
```

and so on.  You'll also have to left join on dbo.tblMsgsOnAir_Type8 in order to pick up the columns in that table, so that's one additional left join beyond what your first query does.  By the way, it's a good idea to post code here laid out so it's readable; it makes it a lot easier for others to understand.

Comment: Sorry for the ugly post.  I tried to figure out how to wrap the query in code formatting, but didn't see the option.  I didn't see an option to to preview the post before posting.  How do I format the queries in the future?

Comment: You can prefix each line of code with four spaces; when you're typing the question it will show your question laid out below, so you can tell if you've done it right.